# High pass filter is not resulting as good as the scope's AC coupling

Tags: ac, oscilloscope, capacitive

I'm generating sine waves by using a micro-controller and DDS module. The output sine normally swings always positive between 0 to around 1V. But I want to generate a real alternating sine with symmetric swing.

If I AC couple via a scope the sine output becomes absolutely symmetric. For instance if the sine wave Vpp is 1.04V. Scope's AC coupling results a swing between -520mV to +520mV.

But if I myself AC couple with an RC high pass filter with 22uF cap and a 1Meg resistor the scope in its DC setting shows a sine with around 10mV error between the swings I observe a swing between -512mV to +528mV.

What could be the reason and how can I fix this to a symmetric swing?

**EDIT:**

Unfortunately using such large cap for AC coupling to obtain frequency  independent solution has problem. I first observed this after sampling the data in plot. This new problem is not related to leakage or DDS offset ect. The problem is the response time is too long when switching from one frequency to another. By response time I mean the time taken for the sine to take its final form when the DDS sine output freq. is varied.

I simulated the circuit to show what I mean see green plot decaying(for this case not that bad but depending on when it is varied and freq. change that decay varies a lot):

[image]

Above freq. is switched from 0.1Hz to 1Hz. Response is even worse for different frequencies. I don't need a crazy fast response but definitely this is not reliable. And here from a real data acquisition shows the bottom of the sine wave how it is varying for many seconds. I also observed more weird transitions for different frequency changes:

[image]

Basically the above RC AC coupling will not work for me.

So I think my last solution is to remove the offset by a circuit like this:

[image]

If I use the above technique there is no issue with the response time. But I need to find a way to fine tune the 1V by a voltage divider and rely on Vref will be stable and DDS have same offset. Anything can be improved for this above circuit?

Comment: Have you checked your 'scope DC offset? It might need calibration

Comment: No the scope is fine see the comments below.

Comment: Does the output of the DDS swing symmetrically around 0.5V?  Does it make it's reference voltage available?

Comment: I took a video there is some shaky behavior due to DDS output https://vimeo.com/302285649 But I cant verify that would be the reason.

Comment: @TimWescott These pins are accessible https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-f28-j1b6mqU/UyXHhSdXL9I/AAAAAAAABLA/Ewrz4oEqlpA/s1600/c41y.jpg

Comment: Looking at the schematic, I'm not sure that what you have is necessarily the best choice for synthesizing sine waves at such low frequencies.  If I were doing it I'd use a high-precision DAC circuit that can swing both positive and negative, and I'd drive it from a microprocessor that's doing the "DDS" part.

Comment: I would suggest you post a new question with this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either your capacitor has some leakage so it causes a bias in the output voltage:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjhPO6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or whatever you are connecting it to has some nA of bias current, or both.

The offset is dependent on the ratio of the leakage to the load resistor in the first case. If you are using an electrolytic capacitor you could change to a low-leakage type or to a film or ceramic type. Increasing the value of C1, if it remains an electrolytic, will not necessarily help because the leakage tends to increase with capacitance for the same type of electrolytic cap.

Edit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1Qrts.png)</sup>

Comment: I replaced the cap with a ceramic 1uF, and I still have some offset problem. Most importantly the reason  I was using 22uF was to make the output amplitude independent on freq. range between 0.1Hz to 1kHz. But now with 1uF I lost that stability. . Output shrinks at low frequencies. How could I workaround this issue? I can use opamp if it would help.

Comment: What are you connecting the output to? Your oscilloscope? Test that with only a 1M resistor across the input and see if there is much DC offset. If you have something else connected, test that.

Comment: Yes to a scope, nothing else connected to the scope or test. I did what you suggested. The output is only coupled to only a 1Meg resistor and I observe with a scope. There is still some offset on AC coupling.  I observe less offset if I use 10X setting I didnt verify it though 100%. If I use a small cap fro AC coupling  like 1uF the issue is the signal attenuates too much and SNR decreases. But there is no stable cap for 22uF I guess. I really need the amplitude remain the same at 0.1Hz upto 1kHz.

Comment: I observed another issue, the sine wave from the DDS module is shakey. I uploaded the video of 10 sec scope screen here https://vimeo.com/302285649 This issue is same if I directly couple the output to scope without RC.

Comment: What is your actual requirement for maximum DC content?  A 22uF film cap (about $5 US one-off) and a 1M resistor with an appropriate op-amp buffer (eg. ADA4661) with +/-5V supplies should give < 100uV offset. If your PCBs are clean and reasonable care is taken.

Comment: That offset would be great. Should I first buffer the DDS output signal with the opamp and then AC couple? Or the other way around? I have low offset LMC6482 would that be fine for buffer?

Comment: The critical node is the 1M/22uF so that's where a good op-amp should go (output buffer). Your LMC6482 is not guaranteed better than 3mV Vos but typically is better. Feel lucky? Input bias current is okay.

Comment: I see so it will be like: DDS--> RC HP filter --> opAmp buffer --> final out

Comment: Yes, see edit above.

Comment: Please see my edit since I use 22uF, this causes very slow response. There were time I needed wait for a minute for the sine to settle. I explained this issue in my edit  How about removing the offset as in my edit? What should be taken care of? Thanks.

Comment: Well, this is totally a different question now. Stability of the DDS vs. reference is likely to be an issue. @TimWescott has suggested an alternate approach with a more precision DAC.

Comment: Is removing the offset worth to try by the opamp I mean?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are using a very large resistor with a large (very likely electrolytic) capacitor. Capacitors have leakage, electrolytic capacitors even more so. How much leakage is acceptable depends on your application, and you choose capacitors accordingly.

10nA of leakage, which is quite acceptable in most power supply applications, imply 10mV of DC thanks to your using a 1Mohm resistor.

Comment: So replace the 22uF cap with the largest ceramic cap you have available (it might be 1 uF but that's OK) and check again.

Comment: I replaced the cap with a ceramic 1uF, and I still have some offset problem. Most importantly the reason  I was using 22uF was to make the output amplitude independent on freq. range  between 0.1Hz to 1kHz. But now with 1uF I lost that stability. Output shrinks at low frequencies. How could I workaround this issue? I can use opamp if it would help.

Comment: At 0.1Hz SNR decreases a lot and the signal attenuates, where I need a fixed amplitude between 0.1Hz to 1kHz.

Comment: @user1234 ceramics can also have leakage. 1Mohm is not very forgiving. Go back to the electrolytic and reduce the resistor instead. Your leakage can also be coming from the instrumentation you are using (e.g., your oscope).

Comment: @EdgarBrown Alright I will also try to check with a DAQ board.

Comment: @EdgarBrown I used a bench function generator to check the scope. The function generator is loaded with the same 1Meg resistor then coupled to the scope with DC coupling. At 0.1Hz The swing is from -520mV to +520mV and at any other freq. exactly the same. The swing is perfectly symmetric without any variations. It seems it is not the scope which is creating the offset.

Comment: I observed another issue, the sine wave from the DDS module is shakey. I uploaded the video of 10 sec scope screen here https://vimeo.com/302285649 This issue is same if I directly couple the output to scope without RC.

Comment: @user1234 ignore the AC aspect. Simply correct your high pass RC to a DC source and characterize your leakage.

Comment: Please see my edit..